# izpack installer not getting instantiated

Tags: java, ant, izpack

I have made an installer using ANT integration and the build done is also successful. I tried testing the installer jar over ubuntu but it's not getting instantiated in windows 7.
The version of Izpack that I'm using is izpack-dist-5.0.0-rc3.

I just get a warning each time I try to execute the jar, which is -> [image: The below mentioned warning]

Kindly provide any assistance, if possible.

Comment: I also am getting this error on Windows 7.  Checked Task Manager and there doesn't seem to be an obvious "install" application that is running.  I do not know the procedure to detect that " . . .there is no other copy of the installer running, . . .".   Note:  full text of first line of error is:  _"The {Product-Name} you are attempting to run seems to have a copy already running."_

Answer (score 2):

This does not necessarily mean that there is a copy of izpack running in the background. Izpack creates a temp file when it gets executed which is created here, for example this can mean that the earlier run of izpack was terminated unexpectedly, in this case the file would still be there:

```
c:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Temp
```

in following form:

```
iz-<appname from install xml header>.tmp
```

You can suppress displaying of this message by either running izpack with MULTIINSTANCE=true

```
java -DMULTIINSTANCE=true -jar izpack.jar
```

or by adding

```
<info>
  <singleinstance>false</singleinstance>
</info>
```

to the "info" section. This functionality is available in izpack 5.0.0-rc5 and newer.